# Music21 and MuseScore can't display .png in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, music21

I run this very simple set of commands to display some sheet music:

```
import music21
music21.environment.set("musescoreDirectPNGPath", "/snap/bin/musescore.mscore")
bwv295 = music21.corpus.parse('bach/bwv295')
bwv295.show()
```

I am getting the error:
`SubConverterFileIOException: No png file for /tmp/music21/tmpwh3jnppk.png (such as /tmp/music21/tmpwh3jnppk-1.png) was found.  The conversion to png failed`

I have made sure to install libpng. I also checked the debug of jupyter and it is saying a couple things:

- `cannot load canberra-gtk-module (I sudo apt-get installed libcanberra-gtk-module)`
- `unable to load printer plugin "qtubuntu-print"`
- `File "/tmp/music21/tmpwh3jnppk.xml" not found.`

[image: screenshot]

But, my temp directory definitely contains this file with populated information

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The solution here is that musescore was not properly installed. I installed the standalone app and installed it through snap

Turns out you should just install it via the command line, then my sequence of commands will work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore3-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install musescore3
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment which will help others using m21/Jupyter/Ubuntu!

Comment: sudo apt install musescore3 alone works at Ubuntu 20.04 now!